"realized itself as"
How to render the English "realized/manifested/fulfilled/expressed/asserts itself as" in Latin? Such as in: "Her curiosity about the natural world realized itself as a career in environmental science." or "deep love can sometimes manifest as anger."
"resulted in" (however we say that in Latin) is a possibility in many cases but not suffice here. I want to convey the idea of almost incarnation/"personification" of a concept or thing as another concept/thing.
praebere se + accusative is perhaps the closest I could come up with as predicate accusative. But it seems to be limited: without clauses so more complex sentences as the first example could not work.
Another approach is factum est in + acc or simply effectum or fit, but those seem to imply change or creation while what is sought here is rather (external) realization/manifestation of something that already exists which is more akin to simple verbs like apparet/arguit (c.f. quae latet inque bonis cessat non cognita rebus/ apparet virtus arguiturque malis (Ovid)) - however apperet + in is not the way to go so it seems.
